# \multirow: Column overlapping onto next column

Tags: tables, multirow, overlap

I have a rather large column that I am trying to format. I want the first two columns to have multiple rows, but they are getting pushed over and printed on top of the 3rd and 4th row. Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c   c   c   c   c   c   c   c   c   c   c c c   c       c   c   c   c   c   c   c   c   c   }
        \hline
\multirow{10}{*}{   LESS    }   &   \multirow{2}{*}{    KVA 2L  }   &   r   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 1   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.062  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.332   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.075   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ .482*   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{     }   \\  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.425   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.323   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.238   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.033   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.070   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.250   }   \\

        &               &   P   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.791   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.165   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.754   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.031   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{     }   \\  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.054   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.154   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.326   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.891   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.769   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.289   }   \\

        &   \multirow{2}{*}{    KVA 3LC }   &   r   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -.820** }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.059   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -.526*  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.012   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.368  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{     }   \\  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -.532*  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.239  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.303  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.084  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.160  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.339  }   \\

        &               &   P   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.000   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.798   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.021   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.959   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.111   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{     }   \\  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.013   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.297   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.208   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.724   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.501   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.144   }   \\

        &   \multirow{2}{*}{    KVA 3LF }   &   r   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.117   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.314   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.064  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.262  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.425   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{     }   \\  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.022   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.028  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.183   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.092   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.205  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.326  }   \\

        &               &   P   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.613   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.165   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.794   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.265   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.062   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{     }   \\  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.923   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.904   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.454   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.701   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.385   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.160   }   \\

        &   \multirow{2}{*}{    KVA 2P  }   &   r   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -.743** }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.096   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.414  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.244  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -.495*  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{     }   \\  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.394  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.218  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.006  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.126   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.144  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -0.057  }   \\

        &               &   P   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.000   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.677   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.078   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.299   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.027   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{     }   \\  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.077   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.342   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.981   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.598   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.544   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.810   }   \\

        &   \multirow{2}{*}{    KAY }   &   r   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.425   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ -.462*  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.278   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.293   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.153   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{     }   \\  \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 1   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ .787**  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.366   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ .469*   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ .714**  }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ .721**  }   \\

        & & P   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.054   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.035   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.249   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.209   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.520   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{     }   \\  \multicolumn{1}{c}{     }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.000   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.123   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.037   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.000   }   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{ 0.000   }   \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:xxx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! I added `\usepackage{multirow}` to compile your code.

Comment: Try `\multicolumn{2}{c}{KVA 3LC}` instead of ` &   \multirow{2}{*}{    KVA 3LC }` etc. - Could you add an image of what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to get.. Could you explain more or post a hand-made drawing?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the `multirow{2}` commands, I guess that the desired output looks somehow like the following:
[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c   c   c   c   c   c   c   c   c   c   c c c   c    }  
        \hline
\multirow{10}{*}{   LESS    }  &   \multirow{2}{*}{    KVA 2L  }  &   r   &  1     &    -0.062     &    0.332     &  0.075     &    .482*      &        0.425      &    0.323      &    0.238      &    0.033      &    0.070      &    0.250      \\

        &               &   P   &    0      &   0.791    &   0.165      &    0.754      &   0.031      &         0.054      &   0.154      &    0.326      &    0.891     &   0.769     &   0.289      \\

        &   \multirow{2}{*}{    KVA 3LC }   &   r   &    -.820**    &    0.059     &   -.526*     &    0.012      &    -0.368     &         -.532*     &    -0.239     &   -0.303     &    -0.084    &   -0.160     &   -0.339     \\

        &               &   P   &    0.000     &    0.798      &    0.021      &    0.959      &    0.111      &   0.013      &   0.297      &   0.208      &    0.724      &   0.501      &   0.144      
\\
        &   \multirow{2}{*}{    KVA 3LF }   &   r   &    0.117      &   0.314      &    -0.064     &    -0.262     &    0.425    &         0.022      &    -0.028     &   0.183      &    0.092     &    -0.205    &   -0.326    \\

        &               &   P   &   0.613      &    0.165      &    0.794      &    0.265      &    0.062     &     0.923      &    0.904     &    0.454      &    0.701      &    0.385      &    0.160      \\

        &   \multirow{2}{*}{    KVA 2P }   &   r   &    -.743**   &    0.096      &    -0.414     &   -0.244     &    -.495*     &     -0.394    &    -0.218     &    -0.006     &    0.126      &    -0.144    &    -0.057    \\

        &               &   P   &     0.000     &     0.677     &     0.078     &     0.299     &     0.027     &               0.077     &     0.342     &     0.981     &     0.598     &     0.544     &     0.810     \\

        &   \multirow{2}{*}{    KAY }   &   r   &     0.425     &     -.462*    &     0.278     &     0.293     &     0.153     &              1     &     .787**    &     0.366     &     .469*     &     .714**    &     .721**    \\

        & & P   &     0.054     &     0.035     &     0.249     &     0.209     &     0.520     &                    &     0.000     &     0.123     &     0.037     &     0.000     &     0.000     \\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:xxx}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

In order to create the above image, I have

1. removed all `\multicolumn{1}{c}{` commands
2. removed superfluous `\\`
3. removed all the redundant column specifiers
4. added the `rotating` package and used its `sidewaystable` to rotate the table as it is a lot wider than the textwidth.

Further improvment of the table might be achieved by

1. loading `booktabs` and replacing `hline` by `toprule` and `bottomrule`
2. using `siunitx`'s `S` type columns in order to align all numbers in the column with respect to the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

based on [leandriis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/134144/leandriis) answer. added some (off-topic) refinement:

- for numbers is used `S` column type defined in the `siunitx` package
- rows are grouped with inserting `\addlinespace` from the `booktabs` package after each second row

  ```
  \documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}
  \usepackage{multirow}
  \usepackage{booktabs}
  \usepackage{rotating}
  \usepackage{siunitx}

  %---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
  \usepackage{showframe}
  \renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
  \renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
  %---------------------------------------------------------------%

  \begin{document}
      \begin{sidewaystable}[ht]
      \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                          ll *{12}{S[table-format=-1.3,
                                    table-space-text-post=**]}
                              @{}}
          \toprule
  \multirow{10}{*}{LESS}
      &   \multirow{2}{*}{KVA 2L}
          &  {r}    &  1       & -0.062   &  0.332  &  0.075   & 0.482*
          &  0.425  &  0.323   &  0.238   &  0.033  &  0.070   & 0.250     \\
      &   &  {P}    &  0       &  0.791   &  0.165  &  0.754   & 0.031
          & 0.054   &  0.154   &  0.326   &  0.891  &  0.769   & 0.289     \\
      \addlinespace
      &   \multirow{2}{*}{KVA 3LC}
          &   {r}   & -0.820** &  0.059   & -0.526* &  0.012   & -0.368
          & -0.532* & -0.239   & -0.303   & -0.084  & -0.160   & -0.339    \\
      &   &   {P}   &  0.000   &  0.798   &  0.021  &  0.959   &  0.111
          & 0.013   &  0.297   &  0.208   &  0.724  &  0.501   &  0.144    \\
      \addlinespace
      &   \multirow{2}{*}{KVA 3LF}
          &   {r}   &   0.117  &  0.314   & -0.064  & -0.262   &  0.425
          &  0.022  & -0.028   &  0.183   &  0.092  & -0.205   & -0.326    \\
      &   &   {P}   &  0.613   &  0.165   &  0.794  &  0.265   &  0.062
          &  0.923  &  0.904   &  0.454   &  0.701  &  0.385   &  0.160    \\
      \addlinespace
      &   \multirow{2}{*}{KVA 2P}
          &   {r}   &  0.743** &  0.096   & -0.414  & -0.244   & -.495*
          & -0.394  & -0.218   & -0.006   &  0.126  & -0.144   & -0.057    \\
      &   &   {P}   &  0.000   &  0.677   &  0.078  &  0.299   &  0.027
          &  0.077  &  0.342   &  0.981   &  0.598  &  0.544   &  0.810    \\
      \addlinespace
      &  \multirow{2}{*}{KAY}
          &   {r}   &   0.425   & -0.462* &  0.278  &  0.293   &  0.153
          &  1.0    &   0.787** &  0.366  &  0.469* &  0.714** &  0.721**  \\
      &   &   {P}   &   0.054   &  0.035  &  0.249  &  0.209   &  0.520
          &         &   0.000   &  0.123  &  0.037  &  0.000  &  0.000               \\
          \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \label{tab:xxx}
      \end{sidewaystable}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]